# Grouped bar graph custom colours

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the following data and wish to create a grouped bar graph like so:

```
data<-as.data.frame(c("a","b","c","a","b","c"))
colnames(data)<-"Y"

data$X<-c("x","x","x","y","y","y")

data$Z<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)

ggplot(data, aes(x=X, y=Z, fill=Y) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position="dodge", size=0.25, width=0.8, alpha=0.8) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","red","red","blue","blue","blue"))
```

In the last line of the code I wish to change the colours of the bars - I would like that all of the bars of group "x" be coloured red and the bars of group "y" to be coloured blue. However as the result below shows, I cannot manage to do this using `scale_fill_manual`.
[image]

Comment: If you want fill determined by `X` instead of `Y`, maybe just map `fill` to `X` instead of `Y`...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get `group` and `fill` mapped to the right variable:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=X, y=Z, group=Y, fill=X)) +
         geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position="dodge", size=0.25, width=0.8, alpha=0.8) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

[image]